# MySQL load: Got timeout reading communication packets

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I am loading a large MySQL dump file (120 GB). I am using MySQL 5.7.

I am getting the following error:

```
Aborted connection 6 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
```

I already have

```
max_allowed_packet = 1GB
```

Note that it specifically says "timeout" error. I have seen questions asking about "error" reading communication packets.

Any other suggestions?

It failed after about 12 hours so it's not like I can just keep trying stuff. I need to get this DB loaded.

Comment: Are you loading locally or to a remote database?

Comment: I'm loading locally

Comment: This can be caused by `wait_timeout` variable that has default value of 28800 seconds (8h). Rise it to the 86400 (24h).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.